# DATE TIME with json format API

Tags: json, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

sorry for my poor english btw , it's not my mother's tongue .

So i created an API using FOSRestBundle on syfmony 3 :
This one :

```
public function getHoraireAction(){
$Horaire = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CBMedBundle:Horaire')-    >findAll();
if(!$Horaire){
  throw $this->createNotFoundException();
}
return $Horaire;
}
```

Entity Horaire.php with JMSSerializer

```
<?php

namespace CBMedBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;

/**
* Horaire
*
* @ORM\Table(name="horaire")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CBMedBundle\Repository\HoraireRepository")
* 
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Horaire
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Debut", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $debut;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="EntreeSalle", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $entreeSalle;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="HeureAnesthesie", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $heureAnesthesie;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Operation", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $operation;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="incision", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $incision;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="finOpe", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $finOpe;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Reveil", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
private $reveil;

/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Sortie", type="time", length=10)
  * @Expose
 */
 private $sortie;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CBMedBundle\Entity\Interventions", cascade=  {"persist"})
* @Expose
 */
 private $Interventions;
 etc..
```

Everything is working , but it seems that the API do not return the true value of fields who have "time" type .

[Horaire.php date time datas on mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUE2x.png)

And this is what i get when i test the API (using post man)

[Error with Date time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FXEu.png)

How to fix that please .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found the solution .

i had to add these lines :

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

//.....
/**
 * @var time
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Debut", type="time", length=10)
 * @Type("DateTime<'h-m-s'>")
  * @Expose
 */
private $debut;
etc..
```